# How to save many h:inputText value of DATATABLE in Database

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

In the web page, I use `<h:dataTable>` to present them.

Example of the JSF page :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.scores}" rowIndexvar="index">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{index+1}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{score.studentId}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <h:inputText value="#{score.teacherScore}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>

<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{useMB.save}" />
<h:messages />
```

The questions are about my ManagedBean : **useMB.java**

1.What getter and setter method do I need to write to store 
 `<h:inputText value="#{score.marks}" />`  value in database?

2.How  to save in database different student marks for same subject using dataTable, JSF and java?

3.What change do I need to do in **xhtml** page?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a collection in the managed bean to hold the values for the rows in the table. Each of the rows in the table will represent a single element from the collection and every element will be accessible in the `dataTable` by the alias name, given in the `var` attribute.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.scores}" rowIndexvar="index" var="score">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{index+1}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{score.studentId}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
       <h:inputText value="#{score.teacherScore}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In the managed bean you will need to have a Collection (or Array) of element, each of them having members with names `studentId` and `teacherScore` and accessors for them.

```
public class ManagedBean {
    private Score[] scores;

    public Score[] getScores() { return scores; }

    public void setScores(Score[] scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }
}
```

The Score class should look (at least) like this:

```
public class Score {
    private String studentId;

    private String teacherScore;

    public String getStudentId() { return studentId; }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) { this.studentId = studentId; }

    public String getTearcherScore() { retyrn teacherScore; }

    public void setTeacherScore(String tearcherScore) { this.tearcherScore = tearcherScore; }
}
```